# Help with a curved part of a model

Tags: modeling

If someone has asked something similar before, i'm very sorry but i couldnt find anything myself. I am a very new user to blender just learning for a bit of fun and to develop some new skills with the freetime I have. I'm just trying to model some random things around the house to just make the modelling process feel more natural and practise what i've learnt. I'm having a problem with this boat, more specifically the front hull, with the curvy surface and slant forward. I've tried to use loops and edited it by hand,aa well as through booleans, but neither come close to the effecf i need. Any help or guidance would massively appreciated [image]

Comment: Add some images of what you've tried and we might be able to help. You can do that within Blender by using the Window > Save Screenshot menu and then edit your question and add the image into it.

Comment: you should probably start with something way simpler and practice first. lots of tutorials online :)

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: could you please highlight the part you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that kind of smooth hard surface modeling you usually need to use simple geometry with a subdivision modifier on it. This lets you adjust the shape manually but without having to move more than a few vertices by hand.
You can use creases to make sharp edges. Booleans also work with it.
[image]

Here's a video on how the creases work:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3PFgmsxktI

For the blue border you could duplicate the edge on the base model and turn that into a nurbs curve, then give it a round profile:
[image]