# Thick parts along curved edge

Tags: modeling, edges, 3d-printing

I'm making a 3d dish and I'm trying to get these thicker parts that will follow the edge on the outside and the inside. The purpose is for 3d printing, so it needs to be manifold.

[image]

[image]

File:
[image]

Comment: So you want that wavy thing to be more inflated or something? Please provide more details

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297444/19307

Comment: @Akshay2005 I posted a screenshot where I got so far, I want to add those 3d curves on the outer and inner surface of the dish

Comment: please share your file, it would help to know your current topology

Comment: @moonboots Done!

Answer (score 2):

Move down the edge loop of your top bevel (do the same in the inner side):

[image]

Select the faces all around and *Extrude Along Faces* (do the same in the inner side):

[image]

Select the top face ring and extrude up:

[image]

Result:

[image]